# Nginx syslog DNS TTL

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system

I'm using sending my Nginx access and error logs to a log processing host using syslog.

```
access_log syslog:server=logs.example.com:12345 graylog2_format;
error_log syslog:server=logs.example.com:12345;
```

I find that DNS is resolved for my domain when Nginx is started or reloaded but never again. The domain TTL is completely ignored.

I tried setting the `valid` parameter on the `resolve` directive but that didn't have any effect.

Is there any way to get it to update without reloading Nginx?

Comment: Are you trying to get nginx to re-resolve the log processing host's domainname? Or the IPAs and domainnames in the log entries? Or what?

Comment: I'm needing to re-resolve the log processing host domain, logs.example.com in my example above. When DNS changes I have to reload Nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to get it to update without reloading Nginx?

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Reloading of Nginx is already a good approach. Alternatively you can establish a VPN connection which reconnects to your backend system in case it's IP address has been changed.